# HTTPie returning "Error processing request. All request parts must have the content-type header set."

Tags: rest, httpie

I'm testing an API with HTTPie. The implementation notes of the method I'm trying to use states that it accepts a multipart query containing a model in JSON format (Content-Type=application/json) and one or several files (Content-Type=application/octet-stream). I'm trying to post a file accompanied by a model in JSON. According to what I understood from the [HTPPie documentation](https://httpie.org/doc#file-upload-forms) the way to do it is passing it as form:

```
http --form POST https://smartcat.ai/api/integration/v1/project/document documentModel@/path/to/json/file taskfile@/path/to/file\ projectId==xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx
```

where **projectId** is a parameter to be sent as query string.

I've tried to set a Content-Type header for each file, however it doesn't seem right, as I expected the `--form` flag to set content-type as `multipart/form-data`, according to the documentation.

I'm sure I'm missing something basic, so any ideas on the direction to follow and how to better understand mime types are very welcome.

Comment: Is it resolved? I am also getting the same error.